# how to write json data from kafka topic to Big query table

Tags: json, python-3.x, apache-kafka, google-bigquery, kafka-consumer-api

the json data from the Kafka topic needs to write to Big query table. and only need to write this data in every 5 minutes

Answer (score 1):

Use [Kafka Connect](https://developer.confluent.io/learn-kafka/kafka-connect/intro/) and the [Kafka Connect connector for BigQuery](https://docs.confluent.io/kafka-connect-bigquery/current/overview.html).

Comment: How can you write the json data to bigquery without specifying the exact schema of that json though?